# how to make a proper ajax call in javascript to django framework with csrf protection?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-csrf

before you mark this as duplicate please read through as i have gone through lots of stack overflow questions but could not find a suitable solution.

So the problem i am facing is i am new to django and learnt about CSRF protection for POST requests. I have successfully implemented these calls on a non-ajax based page. But the current project that i am working on is a one page application. So all the calls are through ajax and in vanila JS not using any library. The problem that i am facing with is that for the first request i get the valid CSRF token that i generated in the template. But after the first ajax call the CSRF token changes. So i want to know what is the right method in django for a situation like this. Should i make all request respond with CSRF token somehow and save them in a JS variable?

Also currently there are two pages. The first is a simple login template which has no ajax calls . It posts to the home page with credentials and if valid it is done. But inside the home there are multiple forms. And submitting any one of them changes the token so how do i handle a situation like this.

PS: i prefer the codes in pure JS not jquery or any other framework and would not want to disable to csrf protection.

I already though of storing the CSRF token in cookie or session variable by that would be defeating the whole purpose of token.

Please if you could attach a sample code that i can learn from.

Comment: Yes you should store that in a JS variable and send it with the ajax request. What exactly have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: @dan-klasson I didn't try that but wanted to know the correct way that it is handled. What about this case if ajax based forms are mixed with normal. What would be the solution in that case?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem that i am facing with is that for the first request i get
>   the valid CSRF token that i generated in the template. But after the
>   first ajax call the CSRF token changes.

I don't believe this is true. Otherwise, any django application would stop working if the user opens more than one tab.

Here's the solution I use on my webapps. It works as expected, but I didn't follow the official recommendation of getting the token value from the cookie. Why? Less code.

## myapp/templatetags/csrf_ajax.html

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('myapp/_csrf_ajax.html')
def csrf_ajax():
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax

    return {}
```

## _csrf_ajax.html

```
<script>
(function () {
    var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token }}";
    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
            }
        }
    });
})();
</script>
```

Then I use this templatetag in each page that I want the CSRF ajax setup.

```
{% csrf_ajax %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The csrttoken is stored in cookies and it doesn't change with every ajax request. I have this code in a js file and add it to any page that needs to send ajax post requests (it uses jQuery and [cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), you need to translate it to plain JavaScript if you don't want to use external libraries):

```
var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```